# Remove Partition Table or wipe HDD automatically

Tags: linux, hard-drive, automation, arch-linux, eraser

My school is currently moving into a new building with new computers, so they're selling the old ones.
Now, I need a live CD to **automatically** wipe the HDD or remove the partition table.
There's no private information on the computers, so secure erasing isn't required (even though it would be nice).

I tried DBAN (Darik's Boot and Nuke) which is perfect except it doesn't beep when finished. The problem is that it would be way too much work to plug in a monitor into every computer.

Is there a software which automatically formats / removes the partition table and beeps using the console speaker when finished?

I thought about using a Linux Live CD, but how do I burn a bash script to the CD so it starts automatically?

Comment: Pretty sure D-Ban can be configured to nuke on boot. Just burn a bunch of CDs, and away you go. I don't know if the beep is gonna happen, but it's really your best bet.

Comment: Thanks! I found out how to configure DBAN, but I'm still trying to figure out how to make the computer beep after wiping.
Does anyone know how to use rootboot?

EDIT: Nevermind, just found out about Remastersys. Converts your existing system into a live .iso file. Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

go to http://www.dban.org/ download ISO and boot on.
Or you can boot on another live linux and use shred utility.